# Do Google Doc Comments (Annotations/Discussion) work with non-Gmail email addresses?

Tags: google-drive

I love the Google Doc Comments feature where you can direct a comment to a user. +them@Gmail.com, etc.)

BUT it does not seem to work with non Gmail accounts (at least the info@mydomain.com and user@cox.net that I've tried).

I got the email but the REPLY to address is a "do not respond". But it does work in Gmail.  I assume it's limited to only working (via REPLY in Gmail)?

Comment: Have you tried this with non-gmail people with permissions to view/edit the doc you're commenting on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, comments do not work with non-Gmail email addresses. You are correct it is only limited to working with reply via Gmail. I don't think it's something they will add. Such a feature as it is would mean trying to cover all use cases of email addresses and any auto respond feature that may occur outside out of what Gmail expects.